# error clause for file_put_contents

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using this line to obtain and save an image from a URL.

```
file_put_contents("./images/".$pk.".jpg", file_get_contents($PIC_URL))
```

I am unsure what the best way to deal with an error is. At the moment it is failing because there is no permission, which will be remedied shortly, but I would like it to be able to deal with situations where PIC_URL is empty or not an image. Should I dead with the error at this level(probably it is better for permission related things) or should I check higher up if PIC_URL is empty, or both?

Which is the best approach?

Comment: The only comment I'd make here is that if allow_fopen_url = Off is set on your servers php.ini (as it may be in some shared hosting contexts), your code above will fail.

Comment: You mean allow_url_fopen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not talented enough to claim this is the best method, but I would just test along the way:

```
$imageDir = "/path/to/images/dir/";
$imagePath = "$imageDir$pk.jpg";
if (!is_dir($imageDir) or !is_writable($imageDir)) {
    // Error if directory doesn't exist or isn't writable.
} elseif (is_file($imagePath) and !is_writable($imagePath)) {
    // Error if the file exists and isn't writable.
}

$image = file_get_contents(urlencode($PIC_URL));
if (empty($image)) {
    // Error if the image is empty/not accessible.
    exit;
}

file_put_contents($imagePath, $image);
```

Comment: you might also want to check the return value from file_put_contents()

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't file_get_contents still throw some error level if it could not open the file? It might not be fatal but it's still an error.

Comment: I don't believe so mike, or at least it's not listed in the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to set a timeout so the script is stuck waiting for a return value if the requested URL hangs.

Answer (score 3):

I would use is_writable(), passing it the folder name if the image doesn't already exist, or the filename if it does, before you attempt to write the image.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Answer (score 2):

try making a function for this.

```
<?php
define('OK', 0);
deinfe('URL_EMPTY', 1);
define('WRITING_PROBLEMS',2);
define('OTHER_PROBLEM', 3);


function save_pic($pic_url) {

  $imageDir = '/path/to/images/dir/';

  if (!strlen($pic_url))
    return URL_EMPTY;

  if (!is_dir($imageDir) || !is_writable($imageDir)) {
    return WRITING_PROBLEMS; 
  }

  $image = file_get_contents(urlencode($pic_url));

  $pk = time(); // or whatever you want as key


  $r = file_put_contents($imagePath.$pk.".jpg", $pic_url);

  if ($r)
    return OK;
  else
    return OTHER_PROBLEM;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both, as far as I am concern. Especially with those dangerous file handling functions, double-checking doesn't hurt. (Where does `$pk` come from?)

Generally, check higher up for nicer feedback to the user and check right before you execute for security. Its hard to give decent feedback to the user when only checking at a low level. On the other hand, it is hard to check for all possible errors (like those file system permissions) on a high and generic level.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm couldn't you also just do

`file_put_contents($file, $str) or die("Unable to write file!");`

Comment: `file_put_contents` returns the number of bytes written. If `$str` is empty, this will fail with the error message even when the file is created successfully since `0` is falsy.